# How to handle KeyEvents in Libavg?

Tags: python, keyevent, libavg

I am having a problem handling KeyEvents.
So I have a div, and when I want to handle Touch or Mouse Events, that's kind of easy with `div.setEventHandler(avg.CURSORDOWN, avg.MOUSE, method())`, but what I do for Key Events?

```
div.setEventHandler(avg.KEYDOWN, avg.???)
```

I cannot find the source in the suggested dic. There is `avg.MOUSE, avg.TOUCH` and even `avg.TRACK`, but I can't find something about keys.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try avg.NONE. Also, the node subscribing needs to be the root node of the avg tree.

Mentioned in the reference: https://www.libavg.de/reference/current/basenodes.html#libavg.avg.Node.setEventHandler